# Как улучшить код что-бы сохранялось 1 раз? Magento

Tags: php, magento

как изменить код что-бы не было повторного сохранения картинки после сохранения модели? что-бы сервер не выполнял лишней работы и сохранял всё за один раз? Вот собственно код метода

```
public function saveAction()
    {
        $id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost()) {
            try {
                $helper = Mage::helper('ffwposts');
                $model = Mage::getModel('ffwposts/posts');

                $model->setData($data);
                if (!$model->getCreated()) {
                    $model->setCreated(now());
                }
                $model->save();
                $id = $model->getId();
                $model->setImage($model->getId() . ".jpg")->save();
                if (isset($_FILES['image']['name']) && $_FILES['image']['name'] != '') {
                    $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('image');
                    $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg', 'jpeg'));
                    $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
                    $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);

                    $uploader->save($helper->getImagePath(), $id . '.jpg'); // Upload the image
                } else {
                    if (isset($data['image']['delete']) && $data['image']['delete'] == 1) {
                        @unlink($helper->getImagePath($id));
                    }
                }

                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess($this->__('News was saved successfully'));
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData(false);
                $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData($data);
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array(
                    'id' => $id
                ));
            }
            return;
        }
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($this->__('Unable to find item to save'));
        $this->_redirect('*/*/');
    }

Надеюсь я понятно изложил свою мысль, заранее спасибо)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я пошел немного другим путём и место id присвоил картинке имя состоящие из случайной строки

```
$img = $model->setImage(Mage::helper('core')->getRandomString(5) . ".jpg")->save();
                $post_img = $model->getImage();

                if (isset($_FILES['image']['name']) && $_FILES['image']['name'] != '') {
                    $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('image');
                    $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg', 'jpeg'));
                    $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
                    $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);

                    $uploader->save($helper->getImagePath(), $post_img);
```

и сохраняет 1 раз и не перезаписывает название)

Answer (score 1):

Я так понял проблема в этом куске

```php
$model->save();
$id = $model->getId();
$model->setImage($model->getId() . ".jpg")->save();
```

Могу предложить создать в базе тригер.

Если используешь mysql будет что то вроде

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER foo AFTER INSERT ON posts FOR EACH ROW
  IF NEW.image IS NULL THEN
    SET NEW.image := CONCAT(NEW.id,'.jpg');
  END IF;;
```